# Disable app autoupdate in Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, application-autoupdate

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0.0 and I don't have much experience with it's user interface yet

I disabled app autoupdate feature by going to Google Play Store -> Settings and I can see that it is set to "Do not autoupdate" in the menu

When I did this about 16 preinstalled apps had already been auto updated and 6 were on the queue. After disabling the auto update, I updated 1 app manually and a few minutes later the next one on the queue got updated by itself.I ignored this because I thought perhaps the update command had already been issued and before I changed the Playstore Settings and may be it cannot be changed or something similar happened. However after 24 hours another app on the queue got updated again.

How do I permanently stop the phone from auto-updating any apps installed on it (but still retain the ability to manually update individual ones)? I especially don't want the pre-installed samsung apps (+ other bloatware) from getting updated because I never use them.

Also, it looks like a some of the preinstalled basic apps are connected to the internet (for example, in the clock app there was a World clock tab, which showed weather information on the side and turns out it was continuously getting information from the internet). Is there a list of such built in apps for this phone that are always connected to the internet, and is there a method of turning this option off, either as a group or individually?

Comment: I don't own Samsung Galaxy devices, but isn't it that Samsung has another app store called Galaxy Store?

Comment: @Andrew Samsung mainly uses google play store by default, the samsung one is optional. These updates are happening from google's play store